# How to send files along with parameters over http

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send a zipfile from my android application to our server and I keep getting a 411 length required error.

Here is the code that I am using to do that.

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.xyz.org/upload.json");
    post.setHeader(C.constants.HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/data/data/org.myapp.appname/app_content.zip");

        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(fis, -1);
        post.setEntity(reqEntity);
        String response = doPost(post);

        Log.v(tag, "response from server " + response);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here and may I also know how I can add more parameters with this post to send them to the server.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer but one thing you're doing wrong is using a hard-coded path (`/data/data...`). Use `FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("app_content.zip")` instead.

Comment: Also, you can use `setHeader(String name, String value)` multiple times. As long as `name` is unique, it simply appends the new header to the end of the headers list.

Comment: @Squonk: I am pretty sure the file path is right on Android. Thats for the location of files related to my app. Thank you for the suggestion regarding setting params as headers but I do not want to do that as we are planning on changing this soon as an api which can be accessed from devices across different OSes and would like to do it the right way. :)

Comment: **"I am pretty sure the file path is right on Android."** - There are thousands of Android devices and there is no restriction as far as the AOSP is concerned which forces any device manufacturer to use the path `/data/data/<app-name>` for internal storage for particular apps. In other words, you cannot guarantee that path will be valid on all devices even if it is probably valid for 99%+. There's also no guarantee that the 'standard' path will remain the same in future versions of Android. That's why you should always use the 'helper' methods to get internal and external storage paths.

Comment: Also - HTTP error 411 means it wants a header named "Content-Length" with the relevant `String` value of the length of the file you're uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `multipart` MIME type, and parts for each parameters and for the files. See [this old blog post of mine](http://zybnet.com/java-http-client-and-post-requests/).

As you should know, an HTTP request (and response, too) is made up of two section: a header and a body (also called *entity*). In the header you specify a `Content-Type` so that the server script knows how to interpret the following bytes (you can also specify the encoding for textual data on the same line).

After the header, the client sends an empty line and an optional entity. A multipart entity is like a stack of *parts* separated by a boundary. This is what your desired HTTP request should look like on the wire:

```
POST /path/to/script.json HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=a2ksdf0?--

a2ksdf0?--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_picture"; filename="me.png"
Content-Type: image/png

<content here>
a2ksdf0?--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username";
Content-Type: text/plain

Joe Black
```

BTW, it's the first time I see an upload script named `upload.json`. What do you use on the server side?

Comment: oh thats just a small script that grabs the files and the paramets that I send and let me access them later. Yes .json doesn't sound right but its an internal api and it gets the job done for now. And thank you for the reply, I am looking at your post right now.